# Depend on Kotlin Multiplatfrom JS Module from JVM

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project with a common, a JS and a JVM module. The JVM  module uses a JavaFX WebView to display a GUI. This GUI however shall be implemented as the JS module. How do I add the JS module as a dependency correctly? I tried

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":myproject-js")
}
```

however, this does not include the resulting JS files anywhere in the classpath. The JS module does indeed create a JAR file with the required dependencies, but I could not find a way to access them.

I also tried simply copying the JS files into my build output, but they are still ignored:

```
configurations {
    js
}

dependencies {
    js project(":myproject-js")
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    build.dependsOn copyResources
}

task copyResources(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn configurations.js

    into file("${project.buildDir}/resources")

    from {
        configurations.js.asFileTree.each {
            from (zipTree(it))
        }
        null
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't kotlin-js generate JS code? If yes, you can't access it directly. You'd need a ScriptEngine

Comment: Yes it does. But how can I access it directly, if I am unable to add the JS code output as a dependency to my module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what should work:

1. Create a configuration for the `myproject-js` dependency:

   ```
   configurations {
       js
   }
   ```
2. Add the project dependency to that configuration:

   ```
   dependencies {
       js project(":myproject-js")
   }
   ```
3. Add the configuration files to the `processResources` task with `.from(...)`, and the corresponding build dependency:

   ```
   processResources {
       dependsOn configurations.js
       from(configurations.js.collect { zipTree(it) })
   }
   ```

Then, whenever you build the JVM project, the JS module's files get unpacked into the resources output directory and then packed into the JAR.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to propose: "from" in processResources is a method of the "Copy" task, but your task is of no type, so from is undefined. However, if you mean a "Copy" task and jsut forgot to specify, you are missing the destination.
Or is there some form of collection task for resource management?

Comment: Oh. By specifying the output directory as `${project.buildDir}/resources/main` it works. Thank your for the hint with "collect".
Also I used task type `ProcessResources` instead of `Copy`

Comment: The `processResources` task I used is the task created by default for collecting and transforming the resources of the `main` source set. Since it is already created by the Java plugin, we don't have to specify its type (which is, indeed, `ProcessResources`).